# Best practices for Silverlight usage in a ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

What are the best practices for ASP.NET MVC and Silverlight usage in a web application? To be specific which libraries/frameworks (like prism) should be used in order to make the application unit testable and develop rapid? How one should pass data to the silverlight part from asp.net mvc (binding if possible?) and vice verse (from asp.net to silverlight)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework with RIA services is made precisely for this purpose.

Comment: I read a bit about RIA Services. It seems it will cut down our development time, as it enables to use domain objects to be shared between client and server with less effort.

Comment: uf, maybe, but I really do not like entity framework as a orm tool...it have bugs and silly solutions for some things(web.config connection string that you have to have on client)

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

asp.net mvc as service layer
silverlight as client
linq2sql for datalayer
nunit for testing